# React native animation change colors and moving

Tags: react-native, animation, jsx

I'm from a new family with React Native. I'm now working with react native animation to change components from JSX to react native. Here are the sources:

- JSX: https://playcode.io/1486089
- Expo: https://snack.expo.dev/@tiendung1601/activity-indicator

I am done converting the source from JSX to RN, but it's still not perfect. Sometimes the color gets delayed in updating the new value.

Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks all!!!

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Animated, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'


const App = () => {
    const animatedCenterToLeft = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const animatedCenterToTop = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const [duration] = useState(500);

    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const timeInterVal = 2080;
        const intervalTop = setInterval(() => {
            setValue((v) => (v === 1 ? 0 : v + 1));
        }, timeInterVal);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(intervalTop);
        }
    }, []);

    const colors = [
     '#007BC0',
     '#ED0007',
    ];

    useEffect(() => {
        Animated.loop(
            Animated.sequence([
                Animated.timing(animatedCenterToLeft, {
                    toValue: -24,
                    duration,
                    delay: 0,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.timing(animatedCenterToLeft, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration,
                    delay: 0,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.timing(animatedCenterToTop, {
                    toValue: -24,
                    duration,
                    delay: 0,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.timing(animatedCenterToTop, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration,
                    delay: 0,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                })
            ])
        ).start();
    }, [])

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignSelf:'center'}}>
            <Animated.View style={[styles.indicatorTop, { backgroundColor: colors[value] },
            {
                transform: [
                    {
                        translateX: animatedCenterToLeft
                    },
                    {
                        translateY: animatedCenterToTop
                    }
                ]
            }
            ]} />
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default App

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    indicatorTop: {
        height: 15,
        width: 15,
        position: 'absolute'
    },
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing that binds the color change to the animation sequence - they happen independently.  Timeouts/intervals are not guaranteed to an exact length of time, and animations can also be elastic.

Instead, add your color change to your sequence, and remove your interval.  I'm not sure if there's an easy way to reference animated values within animations in the basic React Native Animated; I have done it in Reanimated, which I can recommend if you're looking to do more complex animations.

Changes:

- added new Animated.Value (`animatedColor`), range 0-1
- interpolate animatedColor to your colors (`color`), apply color to object style
- start sequence with Animated.timing call to change animatedColor to 1
- double the sequence, set the second Animated.timing call on animatedColor to 0

Full code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import { Animated, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const duration = 500;

const App = () => {
    const animatedCenterToLeft = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const animatedCenterToTop = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const animatedColor = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const color = animatedColor.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ['#007BC0', '#ED0007']
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        Animated.loop(
            Animated.sequence([
                Animated.timing(animatedColor, {
                    toValue: 1,
                    duration: 1,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.timing(animatedCenterToLeft, {
                    toValue: -24,
                    duration,
                    delay: 0,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.timing(animatedCenterToLeft, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration,
                    delay: 0,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.timing(animatedCenterToTop, {
                    toValue: -24,
                    duration,
                    delay: 0,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.timing(animatedCenterToTop, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration,
                    delay: 0,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.timing(animatedColor, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration: 1,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.timing(animatedCenterToLeft, {
                    toValue: -24,
                    duration,
                    delay: 0,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.timing(animatedCenterToLeft, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration,
                    delay: 0,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.timing(animatedCenterToTop, {
                    toValue: -24,
                    duration,
                    delay: 0,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.timing(animatedCenterToTop, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration,
                    delay: 0,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                })
            ])
        ).start();
    }, [])

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignSelf:'center'}}>
            <Animated.View style={[styles.indicatorTop, { backgroundColor: color },
            {
                transform: [
                    {
                        translateX: animatedCenterToLeft
                    },
                    {
                        translateY: animatedCenterToTop
                    }
                ]
            }
            ]} />
           
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default App

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    indicatorTop: {
        height: 15,
        width: 15,
        position: 'absolute'
    },
})
```